# Calculate time spent in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm having a minor issue which is that I'm trying to inform the user how long they've been in a session.

I have a heartbeat that stores the initial time when they enter the session, and also runs at an interval of 60 seconds and saves the new time in the DB.

Now what I'd like to do is show time spent in minutes on the page on this id:

```
<i id="minutes-in-session" class="text-muted"></i>
```

my current heartbeat looks like this:

```
session.on('sessionConnected', function(event) {
  if (session.connection.data === 'customer') {
    $.post("/customers/" + customer_id + "/start", {
      started_at: Date(session.connection.creationTime)
    });
    setInterval((function() {
      return $.post("/customers/" + customer_id + "/heartbeat", {
        finished_at: Date.now()
      });
    }), 60000);
  }
});
```

now I'm thinking I can add some javascript or jquery to update the timer in the class. But not sure how to calculate it. As you can see I also do a post request for the started_at

So what I'd need to calculate is minutes between started_at and finished_at and update it when I set the new interval I believe.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and look for `.done`, perhaps this helps ;)

Comment: Why isn't this just a simple GET process with the calculations done at server where you already have the data and know exactly when user's session started. Seems overly complicated

Comment: well if a user just exits the window I'll have no idea of when they ended the session.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate elapsed time, and convert to mins, code like this is probably what you want:

```
var start = new Date()
console.log("START: " + start)
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("FINISH: " + new Date())
  console.log("ELAPSED MS: " + (new Date() -start) + "ms")
  console.log("ELAPSED MIN: " + ((new Date()-start)/1000/60) + " min")
}, 100)
```

Comment: Perfect that seems to work, only issue now is:
it counts minutes like this: 0.3355166666666667 how do I round it up?

Comment: Use `Math.round(val)` or `Math.floor(val)` to round or take the floor value.